# How to scrape an infinite scrolling webpage ?

Tags: screen-scraping

I have a project in my college for that I need to scrape data of the user comments from this [stocktwits page](https://stocktwits.com/symbol/BTC.X).

But as it has infinite scrolling I am not able to drill down till the bottom

Comment: You could just keep running `window.scrollBy(0,1000)` in javascript? What language are you scraping with?

Comment: Hi, sir, i am scraping with R but i was not able to do it so i used python but still not working

Comment: Some debug steps: Can you scroll *by hand* to the end of the list (comments end sometime...)? Can you read the *first* page of comments? Can you read the *second* page of comments?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Your code hangs, you get limited results, something else? Please show what you tried.

Comment: i was able to work around this problem using a software. 
Thanks for the help.